# submit a form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form like this

```
<form id="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/add_to_form" method="post">
  <div>
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10">
  <a href="#" id="10"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="12">
  <a href="#" id="12" class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19">
  <a href="#" id="19"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
  </div>    
</form>
```

and I want to submit the form using jquery by taking the id. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this?

**Update**
You can see with each link I have the id. I just want to pass this id to the form action.

Comment: Submit where? To the form's action attribute? And why use jQuery to submit form when you can do that traditionally?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You cannot duplicate IDs; they should each be unique.

Comment: You don't have a submit button?

Comment: instead of 'id', try more meaning full name like 'product_id' or something

Comment: anyone can answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to manually trigger the form's submission,

```
$('#add-to-cart').submit();
```

Comment: There is no submit button in the form so I think this will not work.

Comment: I didn't downvoted BTW :)

Comment: Submit button or no submit button, the form will submit if the submit event is triggered on the form.

Comment: @AamirAfridi You *may* have issues without submit button if you listen the `submit` event. But here we trigger it, so it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .submit() function to submit your form through id's ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form id="add-to-cart" action="test.php" method="post">
      <div>
          <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10">
          <a href="#" id="10"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
      </div>
      <div>`enter code here`
      <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="12">
      <a href="#" id="12" class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
      </div>
      <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19">
      <a href="#" id="19"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
      </div>    
      <input type="hidden" name="currentId" id="currentId" >
    </form>

    <script>
    $( ".buy-now-button" ).click(function() {
       $( "#currentId" ).val(this.id);
      $( "#add-to-cart" ).submit();
    });
    </script>

Your can get the current id from $_POST['currentId']
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to try like this. otherwise you cant get result.

```
<form id="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/add_to_form" method="post">
 <div>
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
  <a href="#" id="10"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
 </div>
 <div>
   <a href="#" id="12" class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
 </div>
 <div>
  <a href="#" id="19"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
 </div>    
 </form>
<script>
$('.buy-now-button').click(function(){
   $('[name="id"]').val($(this).attr("id"));
   $('#add-to-cart').submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned in this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297763/sending-forms-submit-buttons-value), you can post back the **value** of a button if you give your submit button a `name` property (and obviously, a `value` to post).

From the linked question (with corrected code snippet):

```
<input type="submit" name="respond" value="Confirm" class="btn_confirm" />
<input type="submit" name="respond" value="Ignore" class="btn_ignore" />
```

The "response" value that will be posted back to the server will contain either `"Ignore"` or `"Confirm"`, depending on which button was clicked.

I would suggest adding these attributes so the form submission will send back the value you want, and **no custom code or custom event is required**. That should keep it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As you have several inputs with the same name, your form looks more like three forms.

```
<form class="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/add_to_form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10">
  <button type="submit">buy Now</button>
</form>
<form class="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/add_to_form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="12">
  <button type="submit">buy Now</button>
</form>
<form class="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/add_to_form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19">
  <button type="submit">buy Now</button>
</form>
```

Now if you want to submit your form(s) via ajax, you can do something like:

```
$(".add-to-cart").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        method: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

But unless you want a fallback in case javascript is deactivated, you don't need any form:

```
<a href="#" id="10"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
<a href="#" id="12"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
<a href="#" id="19"  class="buy-now-button">buy Now</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".buy-now-button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://example.com/add_to_form",
        method: "POST",
        data: {id: $(this).attr("id")}
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the added submit event? Isn't everything mentioned in that event default (or not required) behavior? Other than the Ajax call, but I see no mention of that in the question.

Comment: "Now if you want to submit your form(s) via ajax"

Comment: Otherwise, the submit handler is not needed.